# child object as a parameter

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, subclass

I want to do something like the following:

```
virtual void Aircraft::getImage(GenericImage&)=0;
void Drone::getImage(Image&);
```

where 
`Image` is a subclass of `GenericImage` 
`Drone` is a subclass of `Aircraft`.

How can I require the Drone class to have a `getImage(any subclass of genericImage&)` method without the compiler complaining that a `genericImage` and an `Image` are not the same thing? I want the end user/dev to be able to define their own drone class with their own Image format which extends `genericImage` but no matter what they create they MUST give the functionality to get an image from their drone.

Answer (score 1):

Don't take an out-parameter, simply return the image. Return-types are allowed to be *covariant*. That means, as long as `Image` actually publicly derives from `GenericImage`, this will be fine:

```
virtual GenericImage& Aircraft::getImage() = 0;
virtual Image& Drone::getImage();
```

Comment: @user: The question is, why do you actually want to use the derived image in the derived aircraft? Why not just return a `GenericImage` there too?

Comment: The reasoning behind this is because each aircraft has a different image format that it returns. Therefore, each aircraft will have a different format specific to that aircraft but all aircrafts will have an image.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change parameters this way, nor should it be because it would generally violate the Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP): `Aircraft::getImage` can accept, by definition, any `GenericImage`, which includes arbitrary subclasses of `GenericImage`. A subclass has to conform to that interface, and therefore would also have to accept any `GenericImage`. However you explicitly want to specify that it only accepts the specific subtype `Image`.

Note that the situation is different for *return types*, because those represent things the function *produces* instead of things the function *accepts* (you may say your `getImage` also produces, but C++ doesn't know the concept of an out parameter, and you indeed have to pass an existing object to `getImage` in order to fill it with the image data). Since for return types, going to a derived type doesn't violate the LSP, C++ indeed allows it (the feature is called covariant return types). Therefore the solution is to allocate the image object inside your function and return that (preferably using a pointer — a smart pointer unfortunately doesn't work for covariant return types — to indicate the allocation that takes place). That is, your function would read

```
class Aircraft
{
  virtual GenericImage* getImage() = 0;
};

class Drone: public Aircraft
{
  virtual Image* getImate() { return new Image(); }
};
```

However most likely you'll only use the base class interface anyway, therefore I'd prefer to just go with the `GenericImage` in the interface, and instead take advantage of smart pointers:

```
class Aircraft
{
  virtual std::unique_ptr<GenericImage> getImage() = 0;
};

class Drone: public Aircraft
{
  virtual std::unique_ptr<GenericImage> getImate() { return new Image(); }
};
```